# C++ Interop, Initialization of COM object

Tags: c#, .net, com, c++-cli

I am using COM object to initialized in my C++/CLI code which will work as a wrapper for COM dll . I am very new to both C++/CLI and COM, I want to know how I will create object of COM in C++/ CLI If I am using C++ interop.

Comment: I'm not quite whether I understand the question correctly. What do you mean by "C++ interop"? Are you saying that you have a COM component (which was written in "pure" C++), and you now want to write a C++/CLI wrapper class for that component, but you don't know how to create/instantiate the COM component?